# o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Below is my query in ORACLE which is getting ORA-00917: missing comma error.

```
public boolean setFileDetails(String fileName,String fileType) {
    String query = "insert into Filedetails_PP values (?,?,?,sysdate())";
    Query qry = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
    qry.setParameter(1, null);
    qry.setParameter(2, fileName);
    qry.setParameter(3, fileType);
    int status=qry.executeUpdate();
    if(status>0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know where it requires comma now.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle's `SYSDATE` is a function, but when using it in a query we don't use parentheses.  Try the following query in your Java code:

```
String query = "insert into Filedetails_PP values (?,?,?,sysdate)";
```

Here is a link to the [documentation for SYSDATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm).